# TRIZ for software engineers

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, questions

Would a question on whether or not [TRIZ](http://www.triz-journal.com/archives/what_is_triz/) was a useful framework to know for programmers be a good, bad, or off topic question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Questions about the usefulness of TRIZ would probably be closed since they would lead to extended discussion or polling (making them non-constructive). However, if there was a specific question about how to apply TRIZ in a software development environment that had objective answers, it might be on-topic.

You might also be interested in the [Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/), especially if you are looking for answers about TRIZ in a psychological sense.